# Metodo toString() no puedo modificarlo en Java

Tags: java

Hola buenas estoy estudiando POO en Java y me gustaría poder modificar el metodo toString() para que en una clase me devuelva cierto texto. En mi caso tengo la clase Tiempo(hora,min,seg) y quiero que al hacer t.toString() me devuelva 10h 20m 40s(por ejemplo). El caso es que no me sale ningún error de compilación pero al ejecutarlo y probar el método, no me muestra nada por pantalla. Les muestro el código que tengo hecho hasta el momento. Un saludo

```
public class Tiempo {
    private int h,m,s;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tiempo t1=new Tiempo(1,20,50);
        Tiempo t2=new Tiempo(2,10,50);
        int num=50;
        t1.sumarObjeto(num);
        t1.toString();
        //System.out.println(t1.h+","+t1.m+","+t1.s);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.h+"h "+this.m+"m "+this.s+"s";
    }
    public void restarObjeto(int num){

    }
    public void sumarObjeto(int num){

        this.recalcular();
    }
    public Tiempo restarTiempos(Tiempo t){
        return new Tiempo(this.h-t.h,this.m-t.m,this.s-t.s);
    }
    public Tiempo sumarTiempos(Tiempo t){
        return new Tiempo(this.h+t.h,this.m+t.m,this.s+t.s);
    }
    Tiempo(int h,int m,int s){
        setHora(h);
        setMin(m);
        setSeg(s);
        this.recalcular();
    }
    public void recalcular(){
        int time=h*3600+m*60+s;
        this.h=time/3600;
        this.m=(time/60)%60;
        this.s=(time%60);
    }
    public void setHora(int h){this.h=h;}
    public void setMin(int m){this.m=m;}
    public void setSeg(int s){this.s=s;}
    public final int getHora(){return this.h;}
    public final int getMin(){return this.m;}
    public final int getSeg(){return this.s;}

}
```

Comment: No te muestra nada porque el método retorna un `String` pero no lo estás imprimiendo.

Comment: El método parece correcto (y si hubiera algún problema el @Override informaría de ello) ¿Puedes mostrar dónde y cómo lo usas para ver si allí está el problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema no es que `toString` este mal, lo que pasa es que el método te retorna un `String` y  para mostrar el valor en consola debes de utilizar `println`, la solución seria pasar el `String` a un `println`.

```
 System.out.println(t1.toString());
```